# Point GoDaddy domain to a specific folder on my web server

Tags: iis, web, dns

Lets say I have ordered domain name abc.com from GoDaddy.

I want to point the domain to my web site that I am hosting locally on my computer via IIS. Lets say that to hit this website currently, you would go to '123.123.123.123/mysite/'.

I am trying to setup the DNS Zone File to do this, but I cannot figure out how to get it to point to the "/mysite/" directory.

How can I properly set my GoDaddy DNS Zone file to point to '123.123.123.123/mysite/'?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got your concepts a little mixed up there. What you are looking for is a HTTP Redirect. DNS is simply a way to map an IP Address to a domain name, it doesn't care what the traffic does once it gets to your site.

Think of DNS as a Postcode (Zipcode). It puts a letter in your letterbox. There is no way for it to know that Betty is on the second floor, because that's not what the Postcode does.

DNS will point a domain name example.com to an IP Address 123.123.123.123. You can have multiple domain names, www.example.com and mysite.example.com all pointing to the same IP Address, and the server can be configured to figure out what to do with each individual domain name.

So what you could potentially do is have the server detect that you are requesting mysite.example.com and have that redirected to www.example.com/mysite. This would be the standard way of achieving this.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. As you might tell, I am new to this. So, now I guess the question becomes, how do I tell IIS to detect this and redirect. I am using IIS 7 on a Windows 7 Home Premium, and from all of my researching into it this morning, I do not believe HTTP REDIRECT is an option outside of Windows Server. How can I achieve this on Home Premium?

Comment: Is it possible for subdomain to point to IIS virtual directory?
Here is my referred question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005921/how-do-i-map-iis-virtual-directory-to-a-subdomain