# How do I map IIS virtual directory to a subdomain?

Tags: iis, web, subdomain, virtual-directory, iis-10

Currently, I have a website mapping as following

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/<virtualdir> to http://<IP Address>/<virtualdir>
```

I want the virtual directory to be accessed with just the subdomain:

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/
```

so that it points to  `http://<IP Address>/<virtualdir>`

Im using IIS 10, windows server 2016.

**What are my possible options?**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want http://subdomain.domain.com/ to be accessible by the plain URL http://subdomain.domain.com.
If that is the case you want to go into your IIS:
 1. select 
 2. right click
 3. convert to application

You can then give it bindings just like your base website with your desired DNS entry.

Side note; You can then either remove your binding from the base site that you want on the  or give it the same address of http://subdomain.domain.com but some other port so it would be http://subdomain.domain.com:8080 to access the  and http://subdomain.domain.com for the original content at the base site